# Return value from code statement in Frends process without assigning variable

Tags: integration, frends

In a [Frends](https://frends.com/) process, sometimes I just want to pipe the result of one C# statement into the next element, just like how tasks work, and I'd rather not pollute the scope with a variable that will only be used once.

I tried keeping "Assign variable" disabled on the C# statement element and returning a value as normal, but that throws an error. I would have expected to just be able to access the value using `#result` or `#result[element name]`.

Is there any other way of doing it? Perhaps assigning your return value to some special hash reference that I haven't found?

Comment: "I would have expected to just be able to access the value using `#result` or `#result[element name]`" - neither of those look like normal C#. So if those are valid in some specific context in which you're working, please help us to identify it - maybe by applying some more relevant tags than one completely empty one?

Comment: Yes, this is specific to the [Frends integration platform](https://frends.com/) which I realize is not widely known. I'm not sure how else to specify that, except using their tag.

Comment: I guess I could mention it in the description. I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a smaller code element you need to assign a variable if you want to return data from the code element, or as the [docs](https://docs.frends.com/en/articles/5270981-code) put it

> A Code element that does not declare a variable will only return a String value indicating that it has been executed.

You can work around this by modifying some previously defined variable, or by using [bigger code element](https://docs.frends.com/en/articles/5270988-code-statement) where you can run multiple lines of C# code.

e.g. if you have code

```
{
int temp = 1;
int temp2 = 2;

return temp + temp2;
}
```

And assign it to variable `foo` like this

[image]

then only `#var.foo` is available afterward (temp and temp2 are not).

Comment: Alright, so it's just not possible to return a value without assigning a variable. It's a bit counterintuitive if you ask me, but now I know!